# Edit Text Send Function in chat application

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

i'm creating a narrative game, for that i have a conversation screen.

The user have to choose a predifined message to send it.
The choosen message is transfered inside the Edit Text but to send it, the user have to open the swift keyboard and click on "send".

**I want to create a method that automatically send the message after the user choice. (Skip the manual "send" on the keyboard)**

I tried TextWatcher :

```
EditText userInput;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
List<ResponseMessage> responseMessageList;
MessageAdapter messageAdapter;
String[] listChoices;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chapitretest);

  Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChoice);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
              listChoices = new String[]{"Mdr","Lol","xd"};
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(ChapTest.this);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Ton choix:");
            mBuilder.setSingleChoiceItems(listChoices, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    userInput.setText(listChoices[i]);
                    userInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                        @Override
                        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                            String txtbulle = userInput.getText().toString();
                        }
                    });

                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                }
            });
            AlertDialog mDialog = mBuilder.create();
            mDialog.show();
```

This is my first app, thank you ;)

Update: Why I use EditText :  (Conversation method)

```
  userInput = findViewById(R.id.UserInput);

     recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.Conversation);
     responseMessageList = new ArrayList<>();
     messageAdapter=new MessageAdapter(responseMessageList,this);
     recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
     recyclerView.setAdapter(messageAdapter);
    userInput.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {


            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEND){
               ResponseMessage message = new ResponseMessage(userInput.getText().toString(),true);
               responseMessageList.add(message);
               ResponseMessage message2 = new ResponseMessage(userInput.getText().toString(),false);
                responseMessageList.add(message2);
                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                if (!isLastVisible())
                    recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(messageAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: If you're not intending to change the text, why transfer it to EditText anyway? Instead, just pass the text directly as an output.

Comment: I prefer to show the choosen Text inside the  EditText for the realistic aspect of the conversation.

Comment: I can't wrap my head around this. You are displaying the choices as a list. When a user selects a choice, you want to automatically send the message(as per the question). In what step are you displaying it in the EditText then? Even if you display it in the EditText, how do you expect user to send the message? A timer of any sort?

Comment: I edited my post. I would like to make a method EditText.Send = true